# How do I disable command line history in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, logging

Right now, I'm aware that for all commands typed into the console, the Ubuntu system logs it somewhere.

How can I disable logging of unix commands for all users?

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers to understand *why* someone might wish to remove command histories.  By way of counterpoint, users frequently retype the same or similar commands and can avail themselves of the ctrl-r, up arrow, or bang mechanisms.

Comment: As a tip if you put a space before command (start the command with a space) it will not be recorded in  your history, and up/down arrow keys will not show it either.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting this in your `/etc/profile`:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

This only works for shells which evaluate the systemwide profile like bash and sh, see [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html). Not sure about other shells. Also, users need to logout and login again to make it work.

Comment: @Shi unfortunately I can't approve your suggested edit, so I have to do it manually.

Comment: Funny. I couldn't approve it in the notifications, because I don't have enough points, but I was able to do it when I clicked on edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable history using command

> set +o history

This would be per shell. To make it permanent put it in `/etc/profile`

[More details.](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-clear-terminal-history-in-linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can easely erase your current user command history using

> history -c

useful if you typed a password as a commnad parameter.